# Randomize entire UL elements and not li list

Tags: javascript, html, element

Found this on another answer but a few years ago. Looks like it doesn't work anymore. I really need that for my project... is it possible to randomize the entire ul element and not the list inside of it?

So for example I have 100 ul elements on my page and want them all to randomize on every refresh of the page.

```
var ulList = document.getElementsByClassName("myElement");
const body = document.body;
for (let j = 0; j < ulList.length; j++) {
  body.appendChild(body.children[Math.random() * j | 0])
}



<div style="margin: auto;">

<ul class="i-table yellow myElement">
   <div id="r_tag"><script>ri();</script></div>

   <div id="r_icon"><script>ri();</script></div>

   <div id="r_plan"><script>ri();</script></div>
</ul>

<ul class="i-table green myElement">
   <div id="a_tag"><script>re();</script></div>

   <div id="a_icon"><script>re();</script></div>

   <div id="a_plan"><script>re();</script></div>
</ul>

<ul class="i-table pink myElement">
   <div id="p_tag"><script>po();</script></div>

   <div id="p_icon"><script>po();</script></div>

   <div id="p_plan"><script>po();</script></div>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: But, it seems that what you are doing is randomizing your li not ul.

Comment: Mh, I would like to have the entire UL randomized, not the li. I am unable to find anything in the internet sadly, been looking and testing for at least 5 hours.. and now here I am

Comment: Note that `div` is not a valid child of `ul` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use a proper shuffle algorithm for generating a random order in an array. Below is an implementation of the Durstenfeld shuffle (this is a slightly modified Fisher-Yates algorithm).

In my snippet below I simply placed the shuffled `<ul>`s into the `document.body`. In a real application you should of course identify the parent container for all the `<ul>`s and place them there instead.

```js
function shfl(a){
 for(let j,i=a.length;i>1;){
  j=Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
  if (i!=j) [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]
 }
 return a
}

const uls=[...document.getElementsByClassName("myElement")];
(document.querySelector("button").onclick=()=>document.body.append(...shfl(uls)))();
```

```html
<button>shuffle</button>
<ul class="myElement">
   <li>first random1a</li>
   <li>first random1b</li>
   <li>first random1c</li>
</ul>

<ul class="myElement">
   <li>second random2a</li>
   <li>second random3b</li>
   <li>second random4c</li>
</ul>

<ul class="myElement">
   <li>third random3a</li>
   <li>third random3b</li>
   <li>third random3c</li>
</ul>
```

OK, I added a few parentheses and turned the event-listener-definition into an IIFE. Now the suffle will also happen immediately after loading.

It occurred to me a little later that `element.append()` can also be invoked with *a list of DOM elements* as parameters. This makes it possible to use the ES6 spread operator (`...`) and do without `Array.prototype.map()` altogether.

Comment: shuffle is good too, but not for my project, sadly. i need it on every refresh, but onclick

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add an identifier to the `container` `div`, so let's give it an `id="container"` so we can select it, and then get it's child and randomly `append` to it.

```js
var ulList = document.getElementsByClassName("myElement");
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
for (let j = 0; j < ulList.length; j++) {
  container.appendChild(container.children[Math.random() * j | 0])
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: auto;" id="container">

<ul class="i-table yellow myElement">
   <div id="r_tag">random1a</div>

   <div id="r_icon">random1b</div>

   <div id="r_plan">random1c</div>
</ul>

<ul class="i-table green myElement">
   <div id="a_tag">random2a</div>

   <div id="a_icon">random3b</div>

   <div id="a_plan">random4c</div>
</ul>

<ul class="i-table pink myElement">
   <div id="p_tag">random3a</div>

   <div id="p_icon">random3a</div>

   <div id="p_plan">random3a</div>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried yours. It somehow doesnt work on my bootstrap page, is there a reason why, is there something that can block it from working? Because ive tried it on jsfiddle and it worked, but not on my page, weird...

Comment: @stayarthur Are your `ul` elements direct children to the `body` like the code above?

Comment: [sourceb.in](https://sourceb.in/0Zf7VRe8Si) here is my ul element. i have the content of it saved in a js file to manage a lot of pages, so that i dont have to change each page manually.

Comment: @stayarthur, I can't access the link your provided, please edit the question and add the same `HTML` structure you have.

Comment: thank you. i have changed the html structure now

Comment: @stayarthur, you are welcome, what are the `ri`, `re` `po` methods in scripts?

Comment: its just a function ri() and the getelementbyid with innerhtml text, so that i dont have to replace the text or html on several pages manually, so i only have to go on the js file and change the text there and then it changes on all pages

Comment: @stayarthur, I just update the answer, please check again.

Comment: Arthur make sure you give the <div> wrapping the UL's the class "container" since thats what the JS is trying to find and use to randomize the UL's

Comment: thank you for double checking. still, same problem, it just wont randomize the UL elements at all. i even tried on a fresh html file and wont do anything. but it works on html testing sites such as jsfiddle.net  - this is so weird... other java stuff works just fine

Comment: @stayarthur, you are welcome, I wished that could help you, but it seems something wrong in your environment, anyway good luck.